# How can I repeat column values if the two cells of the nextline are empty in a CSV file

Tags: regex, csv, awk, sed

I'm trying to fill in the first two empty cells on the next line with the first two cells of the previous. I want to use SED for learning purposes.

I'm trying to rewrite this code which works for the first cell and a part from the second.

```
sed '
   $!N                            #add next line to pattern space to operate on 2 lines altogether
   s/^\(\([0-9]*;[a-zA-Z]*\W\).*\n\);;*/\1\2/ 
                                  #repeat 1st field and part of second field of 1st line if empty in 2nd line
   /\n/{P;D}                      #print & remove 1st line, go to start 
   ' Example.csv
```

Input Example.csv File:

```
1000;John Do and kids;DO Family;81002545;110,78;;110,78;110,78;6,28;0,00;128239131;
;;BIKE toy;80009280;23.654,03;-727,16;22.926,87;22.241,71;1.255,38;15,90;128239092;
;;Lego - Toys;80007184;;;634,30;634,30;35,93;0,00;128556670;
;;Lego - Toys;80007200;;;0,01;0,01;0,00;0,00;128714451;
;;Lego - Toys;80007186;;;36,57;36,57;2,07;0,00;128596836;
2000;Mary Jay and parents;JAY Family;81002552;70,10;;70,10;38,17;2,16;0,00;128239130;
;;BIKE toy;80009292;2.019,69;-31,11;1.988,58;1.923,22;109,11;0,00;128239094;
;;Lego - Toys;80007203;;;21,56;;;;128960729;
;;Lego - Toys;80007203;;;21,56;;;;128960729;
;;Lego - Toys;80007191;;;12,82;12,72;0,72;0,00;128635673;
```

Desired output:

```
1000;John Do and kids;DO Family;81002545;110,78;;110,78;110,78;6,28;0,00;128239131;
1000;John Do and kids;BIKE toy;80009280;23.654,03;-727,16;22.926,87;22.241,71;1.255,38;15,90;128239092;
1000;John Do and kids;Lego - Toys;80007184;;;634,30;634,30;35,93;0,00;128556670;
1000;John Do and kids;Lego - Toys;80007200;;;0,01;0,01;0,00;0,00;128714451;
1000;John Do and kids;Lego - Toys;80007186;;;36,57;36,57;2,07;0,00;128596836;
2000;Mary Jay and parents;JAY Family;81002552;70,10;;70,10;38,17;2,16;0,00;128239130;
2000;Mary Jay and parents;BIKE toy;80009292;2.019,69;-31,11;1.988,58;1.923,22;109,11;0,00;128239094;
2000;Mary Jay and parents;Lego - Toys;80007203;;;21,56;;;;128960729;
2000;Mary Jay and parents;Lego - Toys;80007203;;;21,56;;;;128960729;
2000;Mary Jay and parents;Lego - Toys;80007191;;;12,82;12,72;0,72;0,00;128635673;
```

Comment: Can your input file ever start with a line that begins with 2 `;`s? What should be output in that case - the line as-is or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into these two `sed` commands which will do the task:

```
sed '
    $!N
    s/\(\([^;]*;[^;]*;\).*\n\);;/\1\2/
    P
    D
' Example.csv
```

Or, alternatively:

```
sed -n '
    /^;;/{
        x
        G
        s/\n..//
    }
    p
    s/\([^;]*;[^;]*;\).*/\1/
    h
' Example.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need to learn about sed for this example is that sed is completely the wrong tool for this job. If you're trying to use more sed constructs than s, g, and p (with -n) on a single string then you are using the wrong tool and the result will be some combination of convoluted, inefficient, fragile, unmaintainable, and non-portable. Just use awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} /^;/{$1=p[1]; $2=p[2]} {print; split($0,p)}' file
1000;John Do and kids;DO Family;81002545;110,78;;110,78;110,78;6,28;0,00;128239131;
1000;John Do and kids;BIKE toy;80009280;23.654,03;-727,16;22.926,87;22.241,71;1.255,38;15,90;128239092;
1000;John Do and kids;Lego - Toys;80007184;;;634,30;634,30;35,93;0,00;128556670;
1000;John Do and kids;Lego - Toys;80007200;;;0,01;0,01;0,00;0,00;128714451;
1000;John Do and kids;Lego - Toys;80007186;;;36,57;36,57;2,07;0,00;128596836;
2000;Mary Jay and parents;JAY Family;81002552;70,10;;70,10;38,17;2,16;0,00;128239130;
2000;Mary Jay and parents;BIKE toy;80009292;2.019,69;-31,11;1.988,58;1.923,22;109,11;0,00;128239094;
2000;Mary Jay and parents;Lego - Toys;80007203;;;21,56;;;;128960729;
2000;Mary Jay and parents;Lego - Toys;80007203;;;21,56;;;;128960729;
2000;Mary Jay and parents;Lego - Toys;80007191;;;12,82;12,72;0,72;0,00;128635673;
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box and as you can hopefully see would be trivial to change if/when your requirements change.

Comment: I guess that sums the `sed` lesson up nicely... (what round-peg, square-hole... never works)

Answer (score 2):

I know you are trying to use `sed` for learning purpose but I would sincerely suggest you to consider `awk` for this task as your input is row/column based data using a common delimiter across the file.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} $1==""{$1=c1} $2==""{$2=c2} $1!=""{c1=$1} $2!=""{c2=$2} 1' file
```

```
1000;John Do and kids;DO Family;81002545;110,78;;110,78;110,78;6,28;0,00;128239131;
1000;John Do and kids;BIKE toy;80009280;23.654,03;-727,16;22.926,87;22.241,71;1.255,38;15,90;128239092;
1000;John Do and kids;Lego - Toys;80007184;;;634,30;634,30;35,93;0,00;128556670;
1000;John Do and kids;Lego - Toys;80007200;;;0,01;0,01;0,00;0,00;128714451;
1000;John Do and kids;Lego - Toys;80007186;;;36,57;36,57;2,07;0,00;128596836;
2000;Mary Jay and parents;JAY Family;81002552;70,10;;70,10;38,17;2,16;0,00;128239130;
2000;Mary Jay and parents;BIKE toy;80009292;2.019,69;-31,11;1.988,58;1.923,22;109,11;0,00;128239094;
2000;Mary Jay and parents;Lego - Toys;80007203;;;21,56;;;;128960729;
2000;Mary Jay and parents;Lego - Toys;80007203;;;21,56;;;;128960729;
2000;Mary Jay and parents;Lego - Toys;80007191;;;12,82;12,72;0,72;0,00;128635673;
```